# Is checking the UserId before retrieving and committing changes to SQL with EF secure enough?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to ensure that users can't access or modify rows in a table that belong to other users.  After doings some research, this is the approach I've come up with (sample code)

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var myEntity = myEntityService.GetEntity(id);
        if (myEntity == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        if (myEntity.UserId != User.Identity.GetUserId())
            return HttpNotFound();

        MyEntityFormModel editMyEntity = Mapper.Map<MyEntity, MyEntityFormModel>(myEntity);
            return View(editMyEntity);
        }
    }
```

And a similar approach for other CRUD operations:  retrieve the entity by its Id, then checking to make sure that the UserId property of the entity (retrieved from AspNet.Identity.GetUserId() and stored during creation) matches the users UserId before allowing any CRUD operations to occur.

Is that secure enough and is it an efficient way to to keep people from accessing each others' data, or is there another security check I should implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with EF for the specifics of what's possible in that framework, but this is what I would do in nHibernate.

For GetEntity, do the get by both Id and UserId in the query parameters.
It saves on sql server load, bandwidth and network usage as you wont be returning any unnecessary data if the entity is not valid for the signed in user.

Insert: wont be an issue, as you will need to set the entity.UserId to the signed in User's Id anyway.

Update: This one is where you may need to manually verify if the entity.UserId matches the signed in user's Id. But check if EF has a way of doing "update entity where Id = X and UserId = Y" - it will make this far more secure and easier to maintain in the long run.

Delete: same as GetEntity - do a delete by both the Id and the UserId as query parameters. So if the record isn't for the current user then nothing will be deleted.

I guess the general approach would be almost be like treating the entities as if they have a  composite key on Id and UserId.

So the MyEntityDbContext would look something like this

```
interface IMyEntityDbContext {
    Entity GetEntity(int id, int userId);
    int Insert(Entity entity);
    void Delete(int id, int userId);

    void Update(Entity entity);
    //or if possible in EF
    void Update(Entity entity, int userId);
}
```

It cuts down the amount of validation logic you will need to write to only in the Update statement. It also makes it absolutely impossible to Get or Delete records for a different user.